# Обновление переменной в функции Python

Tags: python

Уважаемые коллеги, подскажите, пожалуйста следующее, как я могу реализовать обновление переменной внутри функции, при следующих условиях:

В функцию приходит объект Dictionary типа {'variable': 'value'}, в котором указано какую переменную внутри функции нужно мутировать.

Пример:

1. Есть функция в которой есть переменная width = 100
2. В функцию приходит аргумент mutations, внутри которого словарь {'width': 102'}
3. При возвращении из функции width должна принять значение 102

Я понимаю, что я могу просто сделать:

```
if mutations:
    width = mutations.get('width') 
return width
```

Подразумевается, что таких мутаций может быть множество, то есть на каждую прописывать это - не вариант. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть? Пробовал через locals().update() - не прокатило...

Comment: покажите [example]

Comment: `функция в которой есть переменная width = 100` - покажите, что за функция такая и как в неё попадает эта переменная. В общем случае не проще ли именно этой функции принимать на вход словарь значений, и уже ориентируясь на этот словарь самой выставлять себе переменные. Есть переменная в словаре - пусть берёт её. Нет в словаре - пусть берёт какое-то по умолчанию значение, какое хочет. Если же вы не можете менять эту функцию, то покажите её, функции могут по-разному переменные получать и задавать. Так абстрактно тут нельзя советовать.

Answer (score 0):

Решение вашей проблемы:

```
def generate(x_dict : dict):
    for key in x_dict:
        globals()[key] = x_dict[key]

generate({'test':'100', 'test1':'102'})

print(test) #100
```

Так же стоит упомянуть что такое создание переменных очень нежелательно и такое встречается очень редко. 1000% вашу задачу можно решить иначе и проще.